# Adobe Illustrator - Eraser tool resizes my Calligraphic Pressure Brush!

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, designers

I recently got the Adobe Illustrator Software and have been enjoying it. My main problem is that when I use a Calligraphic Pressure Brush with 3pt Variety and try to erase the line, the line shrinks from its original size. I have searched and searched online to see if anyone else has found this and no luck. I tried using the path eraser tool for a good while but it is really tedious and annoying. If you need a video Example of what is occurring I can whip it up and share it.

Comment: ***Welcome*** to **GD.SE** - Please look through [tour] to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. Then look over [ask] and [answer] a question to see what makes a good query here, and how best to frame it. As currently framed, your question seems potentially off-topic because it's almost a tech support type question, as it would require access to an individual file or machine; screenshots could help. You might be able to [edit] your question to better fit our guidelines - *please* first read our [help/on-topic] page on what topics are appropriate here - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's the way Illustrator works.

In this specific case, I use the Scissors tool and I erase the unwanted path after. This method keeps the pressure variation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to edit the stroke after, and want to keep the shape, got to "Object" -> "Expand Appearance" and it will convert the strokes to an outlined vector shape.
[image: Before - line stroke]
[image: After - Expand Appearance]